# How do I convert my linked group objects to be local objects?

Tags: linked-data

I linked a bunch of objects into my scene, via groups and populated it. I now need to make all the linked groups into actual objects, but I can't find a workable solution. What is the workflow to convert linked groups into actual mesh objects with no further connection to the original linked object?

What is the workflow to convert all the objects in a scene at one time when I have hundreds of objects that need to be converted?

Comment: `Shift + Ctr + A` > *Make Duplicates Real* or `L` > *Make Local*

Comment: When I do that I cannot go into Edit Mode to edit the object and when I expand the object in the Outliner, it still shows that it is linked.

Comment: However when I right click on the data and choose Make Local it solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

- Backup your scene.
- Go to Object Mode.
- Select all the objects in the scene (A)
- Go to Object>Apply>Make Duplicates Real (Shift+Ctrl+A)
- With everything still selected, press L and Make Local>Selected
  Objects, Data and Materials or choose All.
- Set the Outliner to Groups.
- Press A to select all the groups in the Outliner.
- RMB and choose Unlink Group.
- Set the Outliner to Same Types
- Select all in the Outliner, RMB and choose Delete to remove all the
  extraneous empties.