# Blender: How do I unpack a linked instance to make changes to it?

Tags: objects, linked-data, scene, collections, instances

Sorry, but I'm not too sure what the process is called. I basically created an exterior scene full of linked instances by going to:

File>Link>Selecting Blend File>Collections>Selecting the Collection

So basically I'm linking collections from another blend file that I use as a library of models I'm using for this project.

I copied that scene which will be for an interior shot. Now what I want to do is tell Blender, to unpack one or two of those linked collections back into the current scene, so I can edit them for that scene only.

I need to make changes to the glass shader of the windows for example, and delete parts of the land that isn't going to be seen out the window.

How do I do that?

I've tried a few things. First thought, was to right click the object and select "unlink" but that deletes the object from the scene. Looking online, I thought I had it figured out and that the process was to make it local. So I've tried going to Object>Relations>Make Local, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help is appreciated! I've been working on this project for so long, didn't realize it would get so tricky!

Thanks!

Comment: Related (prior versions to 2.8) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77705/how-do-i-convert-my-linked-group-objects-to-be-local-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have imported a linked collection, you need first to select it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*, then select one of its objects and in the header menu > *Object > Relations >  Make Local > Object & Data*.

Comment: OMG!  Thank you!  I can't believe it was this easy!  I've watched several tutorials on instances, but none of them explained how to make the instances real in order to make changes!  This is a life saver to me!  Thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: ...and that's why we're glad we have moonboots here :)

Comment: ah ah thanks, we are all learning from each other  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the current answer breaks any parenting relationships, so here's an alternative for Blender 3.4:

1. Select the Linked Collection you want to make local.
2. Go to *Object > Library Override > Make*
3. Select the Collection again
4. Go to *Object > Relations > Make Local > All*