Why does Blender think local assets are still linked?
I've run into a problem I've never experienced before. I have a large project with many linked assets in the form of other Blend files.
PROBLEM: I created a new Blend file and appended some of the assets (objects) which themselves were linked to external assets. Everything looked good, but I realized that my file size had increased eight-fold--eight times larger than the source file I had appended from. That did not make sense.
I eventually discovered that the new Blend file had localized some of the linked assets, i.e., had incorporated them into the new file. However, the linked assets were still indicated as being linked in the new Blend file. The result was if I updated the linked assets, the updates were not reflected in the new Blend file, and there was no way to edit these assets in the new Blend file because Blender thought they were linked.
I thought maybe the new Blend file had packed these resources, but there's nothing to unpack. Appears my new Blend file had become corrupted. :(
Anybody know of a fix? Thanks.
Blender 4.2, Windows 11

Maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195345/blender-how-do-i-unpack-a-linked-instance-to-make-changes-to-it?rq=1 ?

Thanks for the suggestion, John Eason. I think the file is just corrupt. I don't see corrupted files often in Blender, but this appears to be one of them. Fortunately, I have plenty of earlier versions backed up.
