How to make instanced collection local/editable?
I'm using Blender 4.2.1.
I assembled these arches from 2 different rock models. I have transformed the instances (scale, position, rotation).
I would like to make my composition local and editable.
Though I tried library override/Make/Selected and content or Objects/Relations/Make local/All, I can't find a way to do it.
Can anybody help me understand?
Thank you for reading. Have a nice day.
Nicolas


Maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195345/blender-how-do-i-unpack-a-linked-instance-to-make-changes-to-it?rq=1 ?

Oh, this is the answer:
Blender: How do I unpack a linked instance to make changes to it?
I had no idea this Ctrl+A > Make Instances Real action existed...
Thank you very much for your help!
Nicolas

No problem. You're welcome!
